# JQuery - Add new input field based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/41/)

My application has several `.formContent` rows, I am only displaying one row in the fiddle.

What I am trying to do is duplicate the `div` with the class `.labelAndInput` if the `checkbox` is checked, and place a new one underneath.

The new divs label and input should have the same id/name as the one copied, but with "testing" on the end of them.

At the moment I am trying something like this which does not seem to do anything :

```
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox[name=label1Newline]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).checked) {
          $(this).parent().siblings(".labelAndInput").clone().insertAfter("div.labelAndInput:last");
    }
  });
});
```

How can I clone the div, change the ids/names to include testing, and then append it?

Thanks

Comment: change `$(this).checked` with `$(this).prop("checked")`. It works: https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/43/

Comment: or with `this.checked`  :)

Comment: He is using jQuery, so my recommendation is with jQuery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/42/)**

You should replace :

```
if ($(this).checked) {
```

By :

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
//OR
if ( this.checked ){
```

**NOTE :** *The new divs label and input should have the same id/name*, Be careful the `id` should be unique in the same document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, his code is full of bugs even in a 5 lines code, but this solves the problem that OP asking for

Comment: My comment here was a response to other user that said the code is full of bugs, but he removed the comment LOL

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work.  Is my code full of bugs?  Additionally, is there any way to change the name and id of the cloned element?  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, you want every time the checkbox checked to add one labe+input or like the current code add 1 in first time 2 second check...?

Comment: I have just realised that, lol.  It should be limited to one clone, and if unchecked it should remove the clone.  Thanks

Comment: IMO better to separate model that will be cloned every time in the end of the page then before insert it in the last position (just after new line checbox) change the id like you want check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/44/.

Comment: Thanks :-) Is there any way to limit it to only one clone per section?

Comment: So I have multiple blocks like so https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/46/ Obviously they will have unique ids etc.  So each block has a new line checkbox.  If checked, it should add the clone below the input that was checked.  So each section/block should only allowed one clone to be made.